# CUPS Problem - Printers stop after print several RAW jobs

Tags: printing

I have three thermal receipt printers connected to Xubuntu 14.04 with Model Generic / Text only driver when print command three jobs, one for each printer, sometimes one or two printers stops are left with the job without printing, and the queue print says that the printer is turned off or disconnected.

If I send a new print job to the printer that has been standing prints the job that had been printed and the new, but the new print was incomplete.

This is used in a restaurant so that these errors can not happen.

And I hope you can help me with this problem.

CUPS Version:  `cups 1.7.2-0ubuntu1  amd64`

Comment: Hi elgastelum, I know English is not your native language. I tried to edit it but I could get what you mean in some phrases. Could you review it.

Answer (score 2):

1. For each printer run this command:

   ```
   $ lpadmin -p PRINTERNAME -o usb-no-reattach-default=true
   ```
2. Then restart CUPS

   ```
   $ sudo service cups restart
   ```

Comment: Same here :), if this is what works for you, you can accept it. btw, if you have reference for this or you can explain little bit, that will nice from you.